# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2/Z_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $Z_2$ be the following group of isometries of the plane:
$$
(x,y) \to (x,-y).
$$

What is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2/Z_2$?

Since the isometries are symmetries with respect to the $x$-axis. Then the quotient is a semiplane, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the quotient is the semi plane and the fundamental group is trivial.